# JFrame freezing onclick until the return value is calculated

Tags: java, swing, parallel-processing, jframe, javafx-webengine

I have a WebEngine-based JFrame. In JS page code I call java `openFiles()` method and expect a json string as answer, like this: `var jsonArray = java.openFiles();`. If user has selected some files, I should immediately show message "Please wait...". Reading big files takes a while, and when it finishes, I should show message "Finished". The problem is - JFrame GUI is not updating while the result array of file data is calculated, so both messages appear at the end.
Here's the java `openFiles()` method, running in GUI thread I guess, since it's called from page code:

```
public String openFiles() {
        JFileChooser fileopen = new JFileChooser(".");
        fileopen.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
        int ret = fileopen.showDialog(null, "Open files");
        if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            Run.log("Please wait...");
            File[] newFiles = fileopen.getSelectedFiles();
            ...(some heavy operations to make result array)...
            Run.log("Finished");
            return result.toString();
        }
        return "null";
}
```

I thought of running the heavy operations in a separate thread:

```
            Run.log("Please wait...");
            Thread th = new Thread(() -> {...(some heavy operations to make result array)...});
            th.run();
            Run.log("Finished");
            return ???;
```

But I cannot return anything in this case, because result is not ready yet. I feel like it's easy to solve, but I'm stuck.

Comment: How is openfiles called?

Comment: The background thread must be executed in a way that all the features dependent on it will be executed after its execution.
During its execution you can show something like loading icon etc.
Otherwise it will hang.

Comment: Code executed from a listener executes on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`. The EDT cannot respond to events while your long running task is executing. Your long running code needs to execute on a separate Thread. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrenty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information. Maybe you can use a `SwingWorker`.

Comment: @MuhammadAli I see, it hangs and doesn't show my "wait" message, so I should set loading icon even before, higher in the code? No other workarounds?

Comment: @camickr Unfortunately, my code is not whole in java, so I presumably cannot run this fully parallel.

Comment: You can't do it like that. You will have to use SwingWorker as @camickr suggested.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, I'll try it